# Ubuntu professional theme for 10.10?

Tags: themes

I would like to know about Ubuntu 10.10's new **professional themes**.

Comment: What would you mean by professional?

Comment: @Fraekkert somethings like that http://www.webupd8.org/2009/05/9-great-gnome-themes-with-ubuntu.html

Comment: Ubuntu is *already professional*. And enterprise. And Home Edition. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The themes by François Vogelweith](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/05/9-great-gnome-themes-with-ubuntu.html) that you linked to can be installed by adding a 'PPA'. For instructions on how to do this take a look [What are PPAs and how to I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/5102#5102) - you want to enter `ppa:bisigi/ppa`.

Once you have done this then on the left hand side of the Software Centre click on *PPA for Bisigi* - from here you can install all the themes.

Once themes are installed you can apply them from System -> Preferences -> Appearance.

---

Alternative terminal method: (Applications-> Accessories-> Terminal)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bisigi/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Then go the Software Centre to install the themes as before, and to Appearance to apply them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "professional," but you can find themes in `System->Preferences->Appearance`. All of these are the standard themes that ship with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Gnome: http://gnome-look.org/

If you are using KDE  : http://kde-look.org/

You can download themes,wallpapers and so on.